# pgbouncer long cl_waiting for specific connections

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I have a pgbouncer service that sits in front of a datawarehouse type setup and manages high volume API requests coming in from other services. It has been running for a long time pretty much without an issue. One day we started seeing long cl_waiting issues and intermittent timeouts as a result. No known change in the immediate circumstances that we're aware of.

The bulk of the queries that come through are hitting one specific endpoint in the database. So that was the first thing I investigated. All signs showed that it was performing just fine. I was able to prove this with internal pg statistics, but also by doing benchmarks connecting to the DB directly (bypassing pgbouncer). I also did the same benchmark tests going *through* pgbouncer during some openings in activity. I had absolutely no issues getting superb performance with the benchmark in what should be a nearly equivalent circumstance (threads, clients, query, network, etc.).

Interestingly, while running benchmarks, if activity began again (coming from the normal sources), not only would it get backed up, but so would the benchmark.

This has left me really unsure where else to look, but my suspicion is that somehow something specifically about the psycopg2 connection might be responsible for this as that is pretty much the only difference between it and the benchmark to explain such different results.

When I turned on verbose logging, the only thing that looked slightly meaningful in the logs was a `safe_accept(9) = Resource temporarily unavailable` message. The internet doesn't know what it means though...

Details:

- pgbouncer:

  - pool_mode = transaction
  - max_client_conn=2000
  - max_db_connections=7
  - v1.17.0
  - Ubuntu
- main consumer: psycopg2

  - isolation_level = AUTOCOMMIT
  - max_overflow = -1

Comment: Tge database size will have increase d end your system needs simply more time to process. I would first look fior updates, second  for better hardware and finally see if you can replicate the data and refuce the liaf

Comment: Before upgrading hardware... Are you monitoring the number of PostgreSQL connections hitting the DB? And, do you have a reserve_pool configured? That can give you something to check for in the logs .

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, I did benchmark tests that performed the identical operation, just from a different source. I proved beyond doubt that neither pgbouncer, the destination DB or anything in between is the bottleneck. The issue is something that is happening specific to the server that is sending the requests. That is what is so confounding about this.
I have not setup a reserve pool and to be honest, from the documentation, I don't understand what it is for, but I'll look into it more.

Comment: "Interestingly, while running benchmarks, if activity began again (coming from the normal sources), not only would it get backed up, but so would the benchmark."  Did this happen only to benchmarks going through pgbouncer, or also to ones which bypassed pgbouncer?

Comment: Thanks @jjanes The benchmark would only get backed up when running through pgbouncer **when activity from that server would come through** (or at least thats what it seemed like).

I've updated the description. Ubuntu + pgbouncer v1.17.0

Comment: If you log directly in the real server while the problem is occurring and look at pg_stat_activity, what state are the (up to 7) pgbouncer-managed client backends mostly in?  Sample it several times to get a consensus estimate.

Comment: You say "no known change", but what kind of changes would you know about?  Are you monitoring things like new connections (to pgbouncer) per second, transactions per second, etc. such that if they did change you would notice it?

Comment: @jjanes I looked at the statuses (which I'd done before many times) and it suddenly occurred to me that some of them consistently had `idle in transaction` which totally caught my eye. I asked my colleague responsible for the psycopg2 stuff to triple check (I had suspected exactly this way earlier) what the configuration was and turns out some threads were NOT set to autocommit. Changing that fixed everything... Now we know. Thank you for your questions and help!

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; the problem was that isolation_level was not set to `AUTOCOMMIT` like it needed to be for all threads. Enforcing this fixed the problem 100%.